# How to get more data than the rate limit of 1000 through API?

Tags: python, api, request

I want to get more data from an exchange but the site limits the data request to about 1000. How can i rollover the request and get data for like more than 2000 rows? Thx

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.okex.com/api/information/v3/btc/long_short_ratio?limit=2000&granularity=86400"

import requests

response_data = requests.get(url).json()
```

Comment: There should be something like an offset to get the next chunk of data.

Comment: i have add "limit=2000", but still return 1000 data

Comment: I think this is decided by post_max_size in the php.ini file. This file is around the server side, meaning as a client you will not be able to change it easily by any means.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and then I got the answer of just adding this to my program:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

you can put this anywhere, but before when you do your `print(df.head())`

This is what I entered into my program, hopefully you get your answer,

Comment: or do the same as algo111111